# Passar parametro para nova controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Preciso passar o parâmetro "01" da http://localhost:5934/GestaoDeServicos/Catalogo/Cadastro/01, para uma outra controller.

```
namespace Intranet.Presentation.Areas.GestaoDeServicos.Controllers
{
    public class ServicoController : Controller    {

        public ActionResult Cadastro(int id)
        {

            return this.View(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Quero que minha configurar minha rota para que retorne a seguinte: http://localhost:5934/GestaoDeServicos/Servico/Cadastro/01/00

Onde o parâmetro "01" é o id que veio da controller Catalogo e o parâmetro "00" nada mais é do que um novo "Serviço".

Comment: Você pode adicionar `[Route("Cadastro/{id}/{num}")]` à sua action

Comment: Você pode fazer como o @RicardoPontual indicou, mas eu tenho uma pergunta... Por que você quer fazer isso?

Comment: @BrunoSouza, consegue explicar melhor o seu cenário?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo fiz conforme sugestão. Trata-se de uma navegação linear. Sempre que acessar um "Id filho", preciso passar via Controller o "Id Pai". Como terei 5 níveis, no quinto e último, terei que passar os 4 parâmetros.